# Loosing normal detail when "rebaking" to second UV

Tags: uv, normal-map

what I'm trying to do is bake existing normal texture to another UV map, but the problem is the new texture is way too weak. I need to do this because when I did some hand-modified UV, and add some support loops, result is even worse than without these loops. So I want to bake on automated generated UV and rebake to second UV with my edits.

I've trying to do bake with normal node, also with emission and diffuse shader.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Tangent space or object space normals?  Any reason you don't want to just rebake from high poly?  Or is there some other method you're using to generate your "base" normal map?

Comment: I'm baking on tangent space. I can't bake from highpoly because this final object is a "clean" mesh, without extra support loops so it results with waveness. And thats why i'm baking HP to LP with loops, than having second LP with same UV as the first, I want to rebake to second final UV

Comment: So the way to do this is, 1) don't bake emission from different UV, bake tangent space normals; and 2) do a selected to active bake from an interim mesh, that was baked high-to-low, with unchanged geometry.  Changing your UV changes your tangents, and changing your geometry changes your pre-mapped "base" normals, so changing either UV or geometry invalidates your normal map.

Comment: Same result sir, final normal i way too weak :/